# On Enter event not working inside list box control (Access 2007 vba)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a listbox control that displays search results. What I need done is when I hit the Enter key on any of the search result, I want a form opened up. The problem I am facing is, it works but I am required to hit the "Enter key" twice. Any idea why? I also tried placing the code in the "On Key Press" event, however for some reason, nothing happens.

Here is the code that I have

```
Private Sub SearchResults_Enter()

 Dim stDocName As String
 Dim stLinkCriteria As String

 stDocName = "frmUpdateProc"
 stLinkCriteria = "[ProcedureName] = '" & Me![SearchResults] & "'"
 DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstand the "Enter" event. It does not mean you press the "Enter key", it means you enter a control, it is similar to the event "GotFocus" and is triggered in the beginning when you click on the ListBox

Comment: for further information on when an event is triggered , see http://www.functionx.com/access/Lesson17.htm

Comment: thanks for the clarification. so should i first setfocus on the control and that should trigger the enter? or should i be using a different event

Comment: I tried it with the Keydown event. And that worked. Thanks @pony2deer for pointing me in the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned earlier, the Keydown event worked. Thank @pony2deer